# If $A$ is a Hermitian matrix then $SAS^*$ is also Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, hermitian-matrices

> If $A$ is an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix, and $S$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $S A S^*$ is also Hermitian.

Why is this true? I have seen this claim made in several places but can't find a proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Hint*: Calculate $(SAS^*)^*$ using rules like $(AB)^*=B^*A^*$

Comment: So SAS* = (SAS*)* = S**(SA)* = S\**A*S* and S** = S, and A is Hermitian so A* = A, so we get SA\*S*=SAS*?

Comment: Exactly. That's also why most places don't bother to prove this fact: it's very very simple and short to prove.